# How would you execute a command stored as a string in one line of bash

Tags: bash

How would you execute a command stored as a string in one line of bash. For example this doesn't work but I want to do something similar.

```
echo "uname -a" | eval
```

Is it possible to do this or would I have to create a bash script?

**Update**

I'm using [boom](http://zachholman.com/boom/) to store some one line command line statements. I want to be able to get them and execute them. Something like this:

```
boom echo name | eval
```

Comment: If you specifically want to use echo, `echo "uname -a" | sh` would work.

Comment: @tripleee thank you that works :) Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `echo` specifically and don't mind spawning a subshell, `echo "uname -a" | sh` works.

Answer (score 2):

```
s='<your_string>'
eval "$s"
```

Note that usually there is a better approach in such cases (i.e. most probably you don't need *eval*).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
s="date +%Y-%m-%d"
$s
```

Executing this script prints `2012-02-01`.

Comment: Is it possible to do it on the command line and not as a script?

Comment: Just a side note: some shells (zsh, for example) don't perform word/field splitting by default, with those shells commands consisting of multiple words will be expanded as a single command (i.e. won't work).

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov: Just noticed this beaviour ih zsh :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash -c option like this:

```
bash -c "your-string-with-shell-commands"
```

eg:

```
bash -c "dirname $PWD/foo"
```